# Why does the classObject.getSum() of main function return the sum as 0, when it's supposed to return 3?

Tags: c++

In my simpleClass.cpp file, I have initialized firstNum = 1, and secondNum = 2. Sum has been set to 0. However, when the classObject.getSum() is called in the main function, the sum displayed was 0 instead of 3.

I've tried to remove the sum = '0'; (in the simpleClass.cpp file), but the sum returned will display the memory allocated in the RAM (I suppose).

---

This is my main.cpp file:

```
int main() {
    // Creating object from the class
    simpleClass classObject;

    // Expected to print the returned sum which is 3
    cout << "The sum of both numbers are: " << classObject.getSum() << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

---

This is my simpleClass.h file:

```
#ifndef SIMPLECLASS_H
#define SIMPLECLASS_H

class simpleClass {
public:
    simpleClass(); 

    // Setters and getters for firstNum
    void setFirstNum(int firstNum);
    int getFirstNum() const;

    // Setters and getters for secondNum
    void setSecondNum(int secondNum);
    int getSecondNum() const;


   // Setters and getters for sum    
    void setSum(int firstNum, int secondNum, int sum);
    int getSum() const;
private:
    int firstNum, secondNum;
    int sum;
};
#endif
```

---

This is my simpleClass.cpp file:

```
#include "simpleClass.h"
using namespace std;

simpleClass::simpleClass() {
    firstNum = 1;
    secondNum = 2;
    sum ='\0';
}

// Setters and getters for firstNum
void simpleClass::setFirstNum(int first) {
    first = firstNum;
}
int simpleClass::getFirstNum() const {
    return firstNum;
}

// Setters and getters for secondNum
void simpleClass::setSecondNum(int second) {
    second = secondNum;
}
int simpleClass::getSecondNum() const {
    return secondNum;
}

// Setters and getters for sum
void simpleClass::setSum(int first, int second, int s) {
    s = first + second;
}
int simpleClass::getSum() const {
    return sum;
}
```

The firstNum and secondNum returned are accurate, except for sum. I'm asking here to get a better understanding of the concept of header and implementation files. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's multiple problems here. You never call `setSum`, which is what does the math. You're also trying to modify `s` in `setSum`. You can't reassign a parameter that's been passed by value. Just get rid of the third parameter and return the sum.

Comment: setSum() doesn't modify any member variables. s, first, and last only exist within the scope of setSum().

Comment: You initialize `sum` to `'\0'` (which equals 0). So `getSum()` returns 0 and you print 0. How in the world would it be 3?
And why do you initialize a int with an char?

Comment: setFirstNum also has `first` and `firstnum` flipped